# How do you create only one account for website admin authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a website for my friend's company. I have admin pages which I will have to restrict to protect sensitive data about clients. I have a page which allows an account to be created, but the only one I want to be created is the admin account. I know how to authorize, or create roles, but how do I only have one single account being made. There is no functionality for a normal user, only him (the company owner). How should I do this? I've gone through several tutorials, microsoft docs, etc. I'm stuck.

I don't know what to try.

Comment: You could have a read through this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs Only allow 1 user and deny the rest?

Comment: @EGC - it's tagged as core mvc, I fear that link will not help here.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to call this page once to create your admin account and then ensure it's never called again, so no one else can create additional admin accounts? If so: In your action that creates the user, check if any users exist. Simply dbContext.NameOfUserTable.Any() - please note that this approach is not very secure. We wrote a small command line application to do tasks like this.

Comment: If you need to create only one single account, why don't you just create it by hands in your DB and remove any account creation functionality from your app completely?

Comment: @vasily.sib Would that be secure?

Comment: @DanLeash, sure. What can be insecure in this scenario?